# Store a WordPress tag in a variable in JS file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to store a WordPress php tag into a variable in a JavaScript file? I tried this below but couldn't get it to output anything.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Fade in Contact background
    var imagePath = '<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/img/';
    $('body.page-template-page-contact #content').css('background', 'url(imagePath + bg-contact.jpg) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed').fadeIn(2000);

});
```

Comment: Javascript files aren't parsed by PHP so the PHP tags means nothing in a .js file, and they shouldn't. In wordpress you can pass values to javascript rather easily with [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: @adeneo Thanks. I took a look at that link and I'm still not understanding how to apply it to my situation. Do you think you can give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error, imagePath is inside the string,replace this

```
'url(imagePath + bg-contact.jpg) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed'
```

with this

```
'url('+ imagePath + 'bg-contact.jpg) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should store the image file reference in a data attribute, and then pass the attribute to your function.

I haven't check the formatting of this

In your php stuff you could have  hidden id like below called hiddendiv with no content, you can then create a data attribute for this div with the reference to your image file. if you also create a class you can reference all items in the class with the same data, by just passing the image file reference to the class.

```html
<div id="hiddendiv" data-image="<?php bloginfo('template_url '); ?>/img/"></div>
```

Then on page load look at the data-image attribute of the "hiddendiv" element .